# How to retrieve HTML "style" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="maininner" class="grid-box" style="min-height: 2500px;">
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the `min-height` property, subtract a certain value to the current value and reload the new value in the attribute.

How could this be done?

I have not tried anything as I am totally new to JavaScript / jQuery which I believe from what I have searched on the internet are the most viable options.

For what I have seen there is a jQuery method which is `.attr()` which could possibly do what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: FYI, `min-height` is not an attribute, but a CSS property

Comment: @A.Wolff http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Comment: `_subtract a certain value to the current value and reload the new value in the attribute._` why do you want this?

Answer (score 8):

You need the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$('#maininner').css('min-height');
```

This'll get the `min-height` property as parsed by the browser.

You can then use `parseInt()` to return the value without the px suffix:

```
var min_height = parseInt( $('#maininner').css('min-height'), 10);
```

After you've subtracted your value you can re-apply it to the element:

```
min_height -= 500;

$('#maininner').css('min-height', min_height);
```

I've [created an example](http://jsbin.com/eQotIXe/2/edit) to demonstrate this.

Comment: just curious is parsing really needed here?

Comment: @jai yes it is, otherwise you you are trying to substract a value from a string with px at the end.
Which results in NaN

Comment: I'd say so, the `.css()` method returns the value with the px suffix... and you can't subtract an integer from a string.

Comment: What does the 10 mean after the comma in this: `min_height = parseInt( $('#maininner').css('min-height'), 10);`?

Comment: @MONZTAAA It's the radix parameter, it's highly recommended that you specify a value and that value is usually 10. I recommend reading the following article --> http://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix

Comment: @BenEverard Im having an issue using your code. It works fine but for some reason after it subtracts it reloads the first value again. Im using (window).load so it would do this function afterwards but it seems that the original value changes back afterhand. Is there an event that would do this function after everything is done? Ive also tried (document).ready

Comment: @MONZTAAA It appears to work in my example... can you show code for this issue?

Comment: @BenEverard jQuery(window).load(function() { 
 jQuery('#maininner').css('min-height');
 var altura_min = parseInt( jQuery('#maininner').css('min-height'), 10);

 altura_min = altura_min-40;

 jQuery('#maininner').css('min-height', altura_min);
 
}); You can check out the site where its suppose to work here: `http://demo.open2logic.es/starlitefestival/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=280&Itemid=147&lang=es`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44951/discussion-between-monztaaa-and-ben-everard)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.css()` method instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one `var currentValue =  $("#maininner").css("min-height");`

To reload with new value

```
 $("#maininner").css("min-height",currentValue - subtractValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#maininner').css({
     min-height : '1000px' // can edit as per your needs 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertheight() {
        var ht = parseInt(document.getElementById("maininner").style.minHeight); //gets the current min-height
        ht = ht + 30; //adds 30 
        document.getElementById("maininner").style.minHeight = ht + "px"; // assigns new min-height 
    }
</script>

 <div id="maininner" class="grid-box" style="min-height: 2500px;">
 <input type="button" onclick="alertheight()" />
```

here each button click will add up the min-height +30 px